# how to check view status with respect to superview

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, swift3

Well, I have one UIView(tile) in another UIView(board). I can move the tile in board using panGesture. Now I want to know when tile border is intersecting with board border and when tile is completely out of board.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this methods in UIView:

• CGRectContainsPoint
•CGRectIntersectRect

You have to convert the point/frame
before using them, convert them with UIView methods:

• convertPoint from/to view

• convertRect from/to view